# Redirect to the link in parent window

Tags: javascript, asp.net

In parent page I'm using:

```
function popitup(url) {
            newwindow = window.open("child.aspx", 'name', 
            'height=700,width=800,scrollbars=yes,    
            resizable=no ');
            if (window.focus) { newwindow.focus() }
                return false;
        }
```

Child window has a link:

```
protected void GridView_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("Link1.aspx");
}
```

I'm getting redirected in child window. But I want to open "Link1.aspx" in parent window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this in the child window with some javascript. Look up the `window.opener` property. You can redirect the parent using this: `window.opener.location.href`

Answer (score 1):

You can execute with this javascript

```
window.parent.location = 'Link1.aspx'
```